# Add an additional column to table valued parameters during INSERTion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, table-valued-parameters

Given the following table type:

```
/* Create a table type. */
CREATE TYPE TestType
   AS TABLE
      (someNumber      int,
       someOtherNumber int);
GO
```

I pass this table type to a stored procedure. Inside this stored procedure I want to add the data from `TestType` with an additional id `someId` (same for all rows in `TestType`) to a table `dbo.someTable`. What is the best way to add `someId` to all rows in `TestType`?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test @TVP TestType READONLY
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @someId int;
    SET @someId = 10;

    INSERT INTO dbo.someTable
        (someId,
         someNumber,
         someOtherNumber)
        VALUES
         -- here I want to add all rows from @TVP.
         -- However, @TVP only has the columns someNumber and someOtherNumber.
         -- The column someId is missing. What is the most efficient way
         -- to add the @someId to all rows during insert?
         -- Note that @someId shall be the same value for all rows in @TVP.
    END;
GO
```

Comment: You can't `ALTER` a TVP; you'll have to use a different object.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that I can't alter the TVP directly. I also don't want to do this, I just need to add a value on insertion, so some kind of set operation that adds a column to the columns from the TVP and returns a new table or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `SELECT` from the table argument, and add a column with the constant value:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.someTable (someId, someNumber, someOtherNumber)
SELECT @someId, someNumber, someOtherNumber 
FROM @TVP
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most effective way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test 
@TVP TestType READONLY
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @someId int;
    SET @someId = 10;

    INSERT INTO dbo.someTable
        (someId,
         someNumber,
         someOtherNumber)
        VALUES
          @SomeId
         ,SomeNumber
         ,SomeOtherNumber
    END;
GO
```